# Using MS-Word to produce end-user software documentation as HTML

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Is it possible to use Word to produce an online software manual saved as HTML?

I need to write a manual for a large software system and was looking at something like [Docsy](https://www.docsy.dev/) to write the online documentation. The problem is that static content generation tools are generally heavy to get started (installation, configuration, learning curve, etc.).

Can Word be used to produce some sort of landing/index page with links to individual HTML files for specific topics all authored in Word?

---

UPDATE

I'm not looking to write HTML, so I don't need an HTML editor - I'd like to author my manual in Word, add images, and then make it available on the web site by saving/exporting it in HTML format.

If it was just a single document, it would work fine, but I'll need multiple pages that are linked from a TOC/Index page.  That's the bit I'm not sure Word can handle.  I'd like some sort of master document where I can author each section in a separate Word document and then have them all linked from the master.

Comment: It can be used poorly. There is a reason HTML editors were a thing in the 90s. Certainly you could use something like Visual Studio Code to do this instead of a tool that was designed to literally write anything but HTML code.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't mean to use it to write HTML code, I mean to write the docs normally in Word and then Save As... Web Page, Filtered (.htm)

Comment: No, but there are tools to do this. See Doc2Help as an example.

Comment: @Edward - Unless you are actually going to be writing HTML code, within Word, saving your text based document as HTM document would essentially just create a unformatted text file.

Comment: Doing this is NOT recommended. While Word can in fact SAVE AS... HTML, even the "filtered" HTML includes a lot of Word-specific garbage.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The Word-specific garbage is not a problem for me. It's good enough for my purposes and users can access the docs. I won't be trying to edit the HTML in any way.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks - it looks like doc2help could do what I need. I was wondering how close Word could get to this natively before looking at external tools.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, although Word itself is a passable HTML editor, so you could
directly edit the HTML file and not pass through a `.docx` file.

In both cases, editing either `.docx` or `.html`, to
add a hyperlink to text or a picture:

1. Select the text or picture that you want to display as a hyperlink
2. Right-click the selected text or picture and choose Link
3. Type or paste the URL or link in the Address box
4. Click OK.

To save a `.docx` file as `.html`:

- Use menu *File > Save As*
- Click on "More options..."
- Select in "Save as type:" the HTML type and set the file-name
- Click Save to execute.

Comment: Thanks, though how would I go about having it produce multiple pages, e.g. one HTML page per section? Like a master document and sub-documents all linked. Also, I don't want to be editing HTML. I'd like to do all the authoring in Word and then just export the HTML to publish.

Comment: In Word one document equals exactly one HTML page. If you're ready to learn HTML, I would really advice using a full [HTML editor](https://neilpatel.com/blog/best-html-editors/). If not, then Word is a good choice, although the HTML code that it generates is not standard and is not of the best quality.